# Why do some foods have to be cooked only when the pan is really hot?

Tags: temperature

I like fried rice. When I try to make it myself, though, it never turns out the way restaurants make it. Restaurant fried rice almost has this sort of "smell-you-can-taste" that's not directly part of the rice. It's like part of the steam. I'm probably not making sense, but I remember being told that fried rice tastes best when friend on a really hot pan.

Why is this so? What happens when foods are cooked on something less hot? (e.g. friend rice, steak)

A link: http://www.shiokfood.com/notes/archives/000018.html

> One of the reasons that restaurant-made fried rice has that smoky flavour is the high temperatures and the seasoned carbon steel woks that we use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wok_hei has very good explanations about it. Let me sum of it up:

The geometry of the wok is very important:

- better use of the surface area
- ability to shallow fry big items and deep fry small items with small amounts of oil.
- intense heat for low amount of fuel

The temperature is also very important:

- caramelization (or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maillard_reaction)
- carbon steel, cast iron, stainless steel and others have different properties in terms of heat capacity and heat conduction.

Answer (score 1):

As Kenji Alt explains in his [comprehensive article on stir frying](http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/06/the-food-lab-for-the-best-stir-fry-fire-up-the-grill.html) from Serious Eats (emphasis added):

> One more reason to use a wok instead of a stainless steel skillet: *wok
>   hei* is not developed in stainless steel, as it largely comes from the
>   burning of the patina of fats and polymers that have embedded
>   themselves in a well-used carbon steel or cast iron wok. For this
>   reason, if you have a cast iron skillet, it's preferably to use it
>   over stainless steel.

This *wok hei*, developed only at high heat in a seasoned wok or cast iron (or similar) pan is almost certainly the flavor you are looking for--the "smell you can taste" as you phrased it.

Comment: Is it possible to use this at the heat intended in a standard electric stove in the U.S?

Comment: My guess is that it is unlikely--there is a reason Kenji Alt recommends using a grill to generate more heat than home burners are usually capable of.  Still, you can get as close as possible by preheating a cast iron skillet for a fairly long time so it absorbs as much heat as possible.

Comment: Electric burners, especially those in glass top stoves, cannot generate and transfer the high heat.  The only electric way to get the heat for cooking at these high temperatures is with an "induction wok" at high wattage (3000 watts and up).  A traditional carbon steel wok pan should then work (still need to season it like any other wok).

Answer (score 1):

Wok Hei

Other reasons are possibly the quality of the rice or they cooked the rice in chicken broth. In Holland most Chinese restaurants are inspired by Indonesian cuisine and I asked the people in a restaurant how they make fried rice and they told me they cooked it in chicken broth, then let it cool down completely, then fry it.

So maybe try the chicken broth. Also, cook on gas with high heat (like 4 kilowatts or higher). Food cooked on low powered heat sources is generally less tasty and sometimes even disgusting while on very high heat it is much more flavourful.